# No controls <audio Android 2.2.1 mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

If I visit the http://mediaelementjs.com/ on my HTC wildfire with Adnroid 2.2.1 the contols of the audio player aren't shown. The only thing I see is a black area.
Is this because of the configuration of my phone or can it be fixed configuring mediaelement.js?
I'd really like to know.

I changed the mp3 flashplayer on my site to mediaelement.js and now I am further from home on Android then I was before.

Can anybody help me?

Regards,

Tijmen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.2 browser doesn't support this embedded player. Opera Mobile for Android does (sometimes), but a [bug in Mediaelement.js](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/648) prevents it from loading. I noticed that the Mediaelement.js main page wouldn't work in Android embedded (instead it should give a link that lets you download/view with relevant app).